# Do Python objects originate from a common parent class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, python-3.x

Everything in Python is an object, and almost everything has attributes and methods. Now, according to Object Oriented Programming, every object created in Python must be an instance of a common parent class. However, this logic just doesn't make sense to me.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Which objects don't have attributes?

Comment: A note: methods *are* attributes - they just have the fun side-effect that they can be called.

Comment: *according to Object Oriented Programming*... object oriented programming is not clearly defined... *every object... must be an instance of a common parent class*, erm... no.

Comment: @PeterWood Maybe I structured my sentence the wrong way. What I meant to say was that since everything in Python is an object, wouldn't it make sense that they are being instantiated from a parent class? And if that's not the case, then I was looking for some elaborate explanation for the same.

Comment: You keep saying everything in Python is an object. `=` is not an object, `(` is not an object. I think you mean that in Python every name is a label for an object.

Answer (score 4):

> according to Object Oriented Programming, every object created in Python must be an instance of a common parent class

This is **not true**. It happens that, in Objective-C, Java (and maybe C# too?), things tend to derive from a single superclass, but this is an implementation detail - not a fundamental of OO design.

OO design just needs a common-enough method to find the implementation of a method you wish to call on the object on which you wish to call it. This is usually fundamental to how the language works (C++, C#, Java, Objective-C, Python, etc all do it their own way that makes sense for their language).

In C++, this is done for static types by the linker and for dynamic types (through virtual inheritance) by a vector table -- no need for a common base class.

In Objective-C, this is done by looking up something in a hash-map on the object's class's structure, then calling a specific method to get the signature of the desired method. This code is nuanced, so everything generally derives from a single, common base-class.

Python technically shouldn't require this, but I think they've made an *implementation choice* to make everything be a class and every class derive from a common base class.

Answer (score 1):

The common parent class in Python is object. In fact, although it's not mandatory in some versions, you should always declare your classes like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, **all** derive from the class `type`

this is why, whem creating a metaclass, we subclass `type`

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        <logic here>

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

Also:

```
type(object) -> type
type(type) -> type

DynamicClass = type('DynamicClass', (Foo,), {'a': 1, 'b':2})

dyn = DynamicClass()
type(dyn) -> Foo
```

etc, etc

Comment: No, only metaclasses derive from type. Other types do not derive from type, they are just instances of type.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4]

class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

a = A()

print isinstance(a, object)
print isinstance(li, object)
print isinstance(5, object)

>> True
>> True
>> True
```

Comment: So the common parent class in Python is `object`?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi Yes.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in my life when I was confused about this, the following short tutorial helped me:

[python objects and types](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html)

But if your confusion is more basic than this, then maybe you want to clarify which part of "everything is an object" you're having trouble with.